# Installed .net Framework and it does not appear in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I installed .Net Framework 6.0 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?cid=getdotnetsdk. I rebooted. When I open VS 2019 and try to config a project that version is not in the list.

[image]

When I run dotnet from a command prompt I get:
[image]

Comment: You need Visual Studio 2022 for Net6

Comment: I have seen some manual workaround for VS2019 with different results. But the docs are pretty clear: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0